# Too much errors with play2.0 + java + mysql5.0

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, mysql-5.0

I am still trying to learn how to create a search from with search action and database. However I have too many errors:

- **[RuntimeException: No JPA EntityManagerFactory configured for name [default]]** 
  This error appear when i fix the `application.conf` file like:

  *db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

  db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/search"

  db.default.user=root

  db.default.password=123456

  db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS*

- **PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named defaultPersistenceUnit** when i insert this into : `application.conf`

```
  *jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit*
```

I searched all over http://stackoverflow.com but I couldn't find any answers, and my app still isn't working. Help me fix it. Thanks for help :)

You guys can see my code in here :  [Error : RuntimeException: No JPA EntityManagerFactory configured for name [default]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694314/error-runtimeexception-no-jpa-entitymanagerfactory-configured-for-name-defau)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the different dependencies in your project?

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaJPA

Comment: i added.        "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
       "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final"  but still did'nt work with both :(

Answer (score 0):

in play framework distribution you can find /samples folder. I am completely sure there is a project with configured DB connections and so. Try to reuse that.

have you created the persistence unit to /conf/META-INF ?